# Sum of the sequence between two numbers MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table;

[image]

I want to get the sum of the sequence between the `col1` and `col2`. So for example first row should be `sum(7,8,9,10,11,12)`. Something similar to `sum(seq(col1,col2))`.

Can you please help me to write this in MySQL?

Comment: what if col2 > col1?

Comment: @ascsoftw always it will be col2>col1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we know the sum of N natural numbers would be `n * (n + 1) / 2`. Use the same concept to determine the sum of your columns.

Let's say col1 = 6 and col2 = 8, and as mentioned in comment col1 < col2, so the answer would be

`Sum = Sum of (8) natural numbers - Sum of (6-1) natural numbers`

```
SELECT
    id,
    col1, 
    col2,
    (col2 * (col2 + 1) / 2) - ((col1 - 1) * col1 /2) Sum_Of_Col1_Col2
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: This assumes SQL tables/resultset having a fixed order which is not the case..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, author has already mentioned in the comment that col2 > col1.

Comment: thats is not what i meant SQL tables / resultsets are defined orderless by ANSI/ISO SQL standards .. Notice the topicstarter said something about "first" record.. @TimBiegeleisen 's answer doesn't make a sequence and use `ORDER BY` without a reason.. without that information you don't know for sure what the "first" record is..

Comment: Your query might be giving the correct information for now but what happens if MySQL implements  Parallel Query Execution which is on it's [way](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/23/mysql-8-0-14-a-road-to-parallel-query-execution-is-wide-open/) then the "default" sort might change... As you can't predect which thread fetches which data and in which order and how the data is merged into a resulset..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Tim generated the sequence, so he can do sum of those values which lies between col1 and col2, which is the same I did with sum of n numbers logic.  Order by, I don't think it is really necessary. Still, the only thing is required that there should be a primary key to identify which record this result has been generated.

Comment: *"Order by, I don't think it is really necessary. "* maybe not for the calculation indeed in fact thats solid that was also not mine point of making the comments i have no other choice to upvote for that..   the `ORDER BY` in tim answer make the query deterministic assuming id columns having unique values and will always give a fixed result  your query without `ORDER BY` is non deterministic (random).. So if the topicstarter values a fixed sort always on every execution this query is not meant for him..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, yup you are right about non-deterministic nature of results. Thank you for the Vote up and a new upcoming concept `parallel processing`. That's why i love such conversation, you always ends up learning something new. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

Your question might be a little hard to swing if you table doesn't also have some sort of ID or other unique column, so let's add that first:

```
id | col1 | col2
1  | 7    | 12
2  | 8    | 10
3  | 6    | 8
```

We can handle this via the "calendar table" approach, where in this case the calendar table just contains a sequence from 1 to however large the values can get.  For example, in MySQL 8+ we can try:

```
WITH nums AS (
    SELECT 1 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 12
)

SELECT
    t.id,
    SUM(n.val) AS sum
FROM yourTable t
LEFT JOIN nums n
    ON n.val BETWEEN t.col1 AND t.col2
GROUP BY
    t.id
ORDER BY
    t.id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that there are better ways to generate a sequence table in MySQL other than a raw CTE, but this might the topic of a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MOD((col2-col1)/2)>0 THEN (col1+col2)*(col2-col1+1)/2 ELSE (col1+col2)*(col2-col1)/2+(col2+col1)/2 END AS col_sum
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Not sure where you got that from the query, there is no such assumption required in the query.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. If anyone wants the arithmetic explanation : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842152/finding-the-sum-of-numbers-between-any-two-given-numbers

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case where `col2 > col1`, there is a formula for summing up an arithmetic progression between two numbers. I have implemented it below

```
select ((col2−col1+1)*(col1+col2))/2 end as seq_sum
from your_table
```

Can also be expressed as:

```
select (square(col2)-square(col1)+col1+col2)/2 end as seq_sum
from your_table
```